# Django Admin - How to (automatically) adding data to related table that can then be used to filter results?

Tags: django, filter, admin

I have tables that share information in a single related table via foreign keys. The relationships work as expected, however, I'm trying to figure out how to automatically populate fields that are then used to filter the results. I hope the example below illustrates what I'm trying to do.

In the Models:

```
class UtilType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.CharField()

    # following boolean fields used to filter table

    is_address = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_phone = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_email = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_domain = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Address(models.Model):
    address_type = models.ForeignKey(
        UtilType,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="addresses",
        limit_choices_to={'is_address': True}
    )

class PhoneType(models.Model):
    phone_type = models.ForeignKey(
        UtilType,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="addresses",
        limit_choices_to={'is_phone': True}
    )
... more models with similar schema
```

In the Admin:

```
class ContactPhoneNumberInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = PhoneNumber
    min_num = 0
    max_num = 5
    extra = 0
    exclude = ["company"]
    fields = (
        ("phone_type", "country", "phone_number"),
    )


class ContactEmailAddressInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = EmailAddress
    min_num = 0
    max_num = 5
    extra = 0
    exclude = ["company"]
    fields = (
        ("email_type", "email_address"),
    )

.... more inlines w/ similar structure

@admin.register(Contact)
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (
        "company",
        ("name_first", "name_middle", "name_last",),
        ("name_salutation", "name_suffix", "title"),
    )

    inlines = [
        ContactPhoneNumberInline,
        ContactEmailAddressInline,
        ContactDomainInline,
        ContactAddressInline
    ]
```

When editing a contact, the action is as expected. I can add information to each type and the types show filtered as directed in the ForeignKeys.

However, the admin window for UtilType has the boolean selection fields: is_address, is_phone, is_email, is_domain so the user must select this to be filtered correctly. I can hide these fields, with the exclude method.

But how do I automatically populate the right boolean (=True) based on which inline is currently being used?

Would it be best to use a save override method in the models, in the admin, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to do this in the Django admin. If someone knows how it would be good information. I'll deal with the action in the front end once it's developed. I'm not sure it's worth the effort in the admin.